# Installing Aauth doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation, frameworks, config

i'm new on CodeIgniter and i try to install [Aauth](https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth). But the installation [Guide](https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth/wiki/2)-Installation-and-Configuration) is not so clear.

I put the application/libraries/Aauth.php in libraries, application/config/aauth.php in config and  application/controller/example.php in controller.

Next I import the sql file in phpmyadmin (with aauth for DB name). After that i put the halpers in helper folder even if it's not mentionned. Same for languages.

And then

> You must set up database connections from
>   application/config/database.php

I tried `database' => 'aauth'`.

> You can also make some changes on application/config/aauth.php"

I don't know what to do? I have never used a framework before.

I created a controller and put `$this->load->library("Aauth");` in __construct, and did the tutorial.

Problems are:

- **Fatal error**: Call to undefined method Aauth::deny()
- If i dont use the deny function, there is no error but when i look in the DB **I only have legolas and no frodo or gandalf**. But all perms and groups are there.
- If I give "immortality to hobbits", it still say that hobbits do **not** "immortality".

I work with Xampp and Codeigniter 3 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to change anything in your database config file. Just make sure `db_profile` in the Aauth config matches the name of the database `active_group`.

As for the Aauth config, for CI3, change `use_cookies` to `false`.

To load the library, change the name to lowercase, `$this->load->library("aauth");`